# Javascript regex: replace letters near any number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
F1 F#1 F2 F#2
```

I want to convert it to:

```
f1 F1 f2 F2
```

Numbers near `f/F` can be `0` to `9`

Is it possible to do this with regex? Thanks you!

Comment: Yes it certainly is possible. If you want to know *how to do it*, I suggest you read the [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you have any attempts that you'd be able to include in your post? You'll in general receive more assistance here when you can demonstrate your own efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using back-references. Putting parentheses around sections of your regular expression allows you to reference them in a return function (in order from left to right).

The following code works like you specified, first by changing the instances without # to lower case, then using a second regex to replace the ones with #s.

```
a = "F1 F#1 F2 F#2";
b = a.replace(/([A-Za-z])([0-9])/g,function(match,$1,$2,original){return $1.toLowerCase() + $2;}).replace(/([A-Za-z])#([0-9])/g,"$1$2");
//b = f1 F1 f2 F2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
str = str.replace(/#/g, "");
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX5qN1/1)

Comment: This gives `F1 F1 F2 F2`.

Comment: That does not change the letters without the `#` next to them to lowercase . . .